# BindingResult/Errors not declared immediately after the model atrribute, but no problem, why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, data-binding

I am reading some legacy code in my team and I found that some handler methods don't have `BindingResult`/`Errors` declared right after model attribute, but the code is working well without any issue. That is conflict with my previous understanding of springMVC on this topic.

For example, one handler method looks like this

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public String initateSearchData(HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("searchData") SearchData searchData, Model model, Errors errors).
```

Could anyone tell me why the error "An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute" is not shown up in this case?

Comment: I doubt that that is a handler method, but rather a method being invoked from another handler method and arguments get passed in. Hence not a handler met in the sense of it being invoked through the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

Comment: Hi Deinum, thanks for the reply. This method has @RequestMapping(value = "/xxx") on top of it. I think it is a handler method. I just updated the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Spring’s documentation says: The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have more that one model object and Spring will create a separate BindingResult instance for each of them.
Below code explains the scenario

Problem:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "addUser")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm,
        ModelMap map, BindingResult results) {

        if (results.hasErrors()) {
            return "add_user_form";
        }

        return "add_user_success";
    }
    //...
}
```

Above code gives java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature.

Solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addUser")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm,
    BindingResult results, ModelMap map)
```

Whenever you want to define BindingResult object in your controller method, declare it right after the (@ModelAttribute) model attribute.